# After changing my flutter android icons this happened

Tags: android, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\pc\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_dummy\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.flutter_dummy:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Firstly this is not a youtube video title. Mention your problem in brief in your question title itself and then explain the problem in the body. Secondly don't just include the error message, add the relevant lines of code that caused the error. Read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0):

@Viraj D is right as you need to post it in amore ellaborate and short manner,

probable sln: check your manifest ,in the android/app directory and confirm that the mipmap/ic_launcher is referenced well, or if it actually exists